# chktex disable warning about ~ for certain macros when using cleveref with varioref

Tags: cleveref, varioref, syntax-checker, chktex

Is there any way, other than adding per-line suppressions (i.e., `%chktex 2`) or per warning suppressions to get chktex to stop warning me when `\vref` and `\eqref` are preceded by spaces?

I am running chktex v1.7.2 *WITHOUT* the `-g` (use global chktexrc) flag and *WITH* the `-l` flag pointing to a local `.chktexrc` file, in which I have removed `\vref` and `\eqref` from the `Linker` options section. (Linker controls warning about needed non-breaking space when macros like `\ref` are used.) Despite removing these items under the `Linker` section, I still get warnings (warning #2) about them.

Does anyone know a way to solve this without entirely disabling warning number 2 or inserting line level suppressions everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems there is a documentation bug with chktex and the `-g` flag *DISABLES* the default chktexrc file. Using the `-g` flag fixes my problem.

Comment: I admit, the documentation is a bit confusing.  Actually, -g1 will enable the global rc, and -g0 will disable it.  But -g is a synonym for -g0.  The default is to read the global rc.